# How to Resolve Error Sending Email Using nodemailer googleapi?

Tags: node.js, google-api, nodemailer

Last week I initially posted this asking for help using nodemailer and googleapi. I'm trying to use `nodemailer` and `googleapis` to send an email. I have set up my project in https://console.cloud.google.com/ and have set my CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI and REFRESH_TOKEN in a .env and have confirmed that the values are being populated. In debug mode I have noticed the following error stack when I send the error:

```
     'Error: invalid_grant\n    at Gaxios._request (/Users/ENV/Tutoring-Invoice-Management-System/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:130:23)\n    at processTicksAndRejections 
(node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    
at async OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache (/Users/ENV/Tutoring-Invoice-Management-System/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:174:21)\n    
at async OAuth2Client.refreshAccessTokenAsync (/Users/ENV/Tutoring-Invoice-Management-System/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:198:19)\n    
at async OAuth2Client.getAccessTokenAsync (/Users/ENV/Tutoring-Invoice-Management-System/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:227:23)\n    
at async sendMail (/Users/ENV/Tutoring-Invoice-Management-System/service/send-email.js:17:29)'
```

The code is below. I have edited it based on an answer to the question already. My question now is, why am I getting the `invalid_grant` error? Based on the formal documentation I have set everything up correctly in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient. But perhaps there is an issue there?

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
require('dotenv').config();

console.log("CLIENT_ID: " + process.env.CLIENT_ID);
console.log("CLIENT_SECRET: " + process.env.CLIENT_SECRET);
console.log("CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI: " + process.env.REDIRECT_URI);
console.log("REFRESH_TOKEN: " + process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN);

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(process.env.CLIENT_ID, process.env.CLIENT_SECRET, process.env.REDIRECT_URI);
console.log("oAuth2Client: " + oAuth2Client);

oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN})

async function sendMail() {
    try {
        const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()
    
        const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.gmail.com",
          port: 465,
          secure: true,
          auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2'
          }
        });
    
        const mailOptions = {
          from: 'envolonakis@gmail.com',
          to: 'envolonakis@gmail.com',
          subject: "Test Email API Subject",
          text: "Test Email API Text",
          html: "<h1> Test Email API HTML </h1>",
          auth: {
            user: process.env.OWNER_EMAIL,
            accessToken: accessToken.token
          }
        }
    
        const result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);  
        return error;
      }
}

    
sendMail()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#example-5), this is what you need to use:

```
  try {

    const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()

    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2'
      }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.OWNER_EMAIL,
      to: process.env.RECIPIENT,
      subject: "Test Email API Subject",
      text: "Test Email API Text",
      html: "<h1> Test Email API HTML </h1>",
      auth: {
        user: process.env.OWNER_EMAIL,
        accessToken: accessToken.token
      }
    }

    const result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
```

One error that you have whilst using the google api authentication library is with the token. You were passing the complete token object to the auth configuration of nodemailer instead of just the access token string. Another thing to keep in mind, adding or removing parameters to the auth configuration of nodemailer will lead to different errors.

Comment: I tried this and I still get an error, that being said, I have debugged through and see the following error: Code 400 'Error: invalid_grant\n    at Gaxios._request'. I will create add more detail to the post about this but any idea how to set this up properly for this error?

Comment: Does `await` have any effect here? The documentation for `.sendMail` says it returns `void`.

Comment: @samurai_jane It does. Since it is inside a try-catch, it will wait for the process to finish or else the error will be catched and returned. Otherwise, if you don't care about what happens, you don't need to put the result in a variable, neither use the await.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Morfinismo 's solution in addition to creating a new oAuth on https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground resolved my issue.