# Can't send nodemailer using Oauth2 by Google cloud (responseCode: 530)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, nodemailer

I've already configured two GMAIL accounts to integrate **nodemailer** with **Oauth2** from **Google cloud**, the first time I've done it I could successfully send GMAIL's email from my nodejs application. However, today I've made the same steps I've already done before and It's throwing an error when I try to send an e-mail.

> Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required

Some answers on internet says I need to activate [less secure app](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) on google, but since May,2022 this option was deactivate by google, so I can't do it.

All the steps I made to set up the Oauth2 on Google cloud (summary):

1. Create a **new project**
2. Eneabled services and API's
3. Created a new Oauth2 on **OAuth consent screen**
4. Created new credential, web application, with redirecting: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
5. Added **test users** on OAuth consent screen
6. On **oauthplayground** selected **'https://mail.google.com'** service and added CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET, then click on **Exchange authorization code for tokens**

This is the same set up I always do when I need to configure nodejs with GMAIL, I should work, then I copy all necessary values to node.js CLIENT_ID , CLIENT_SECRET, refresh_tokens ...

---

Now I would like to share to important `.js` files related with nodemailer and GoogleApis, respectively:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const urlUtil = require('../utils/urlUtil');
const config = require(urlUtil.getPath('../config.min.js'));
const googleApiUtil = require(urlUtil.getPath('../utils/googleApiUtil.min.js'));

/**
 * Send generic email
 * @param {*} destination to
 * @param {*} subject title of the email
 * @param {*} html html content for email template
 * @returns promise
 */
function sendEmail(destination, subject, html) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        googleApiUtil.getCredentials().then((credentials) => {
            try {
                let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    service: config.mail.service,
                    auth: {
                        type: 'OAuth2',
                        user: config.mail.user,
                        clientId: credentials.client_id,
                        clientSecret: credentials.client_secret,
                        refreshToken: credentials.refresh_token,
                        accessToken: credentials.accessToken
                    }, tls: {
                        rejectUnauthorized: false
                    }

                });
                let mailOptions = {};

                mailOptions = {
                    from: `IARA <${config.mail.user}>`,
                    to: destination,
                    subject: subject,
                    html: html,
                    attachments: null

                };

                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, resolve);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    });
}

//This should send an email to destinantion
sendEmail('adriel.kirch.1@gmail.com','teste','testando').then(r=> {
    console.log(r)
})

/**
 * Exports
 */
module.exports = {
    sendEmail
};
```

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const urlUtil = require('../utils/urlUtil');
const config = require(urlUtil.getPath('../config.min.js'));
const fsUtil = require(urlUtil.getPath('../utils/fsUtil.min.js'));
//Basic credentials
const CLIENT_ID = '4123123..';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'GO...';

//https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground';
let refresh_token = '';
let accessToken = '';

if (!config.mail.refresh_token) {
    refresh_token = '1//...';
} else {
    refresh_token = config.mail.refresh_token;
}

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);


oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: refresh_token,
});

oAuth2Client.refreshAccessToken((err, tokens) => {
    console.log(tokens)
    accessToken = tokens['access_token'];
    refresh_token = tokens['refresh_token'];
    //Set Config
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    config.mail.accessToken = accessToken;
    config.mail.refresh_token = refresh_token;
    fsUtil.updateCredentials(config);
});

/**
 * @returns Get credentials
 */
async function getCredentials() {
    return {
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
        refresh_token: refresh_token,
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        accessToken: accessToken
    };
}


module.exports = {
    getCredentials
};
```

Conclusion:

I not even know if my mistake is on Oauth2 configuration or in Nodejs, I belive it's on Google cloud, but I'm not really sure, If anyone more experienced know how I can solve it let me know, Thanks a lott

Fullstack trace:

> Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
> 530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError dy43-20020a056870c7ab00b00101cdb417f1sm5627633oab.22 - gsmtp
> at SMTPConnection._formatError (c:\Javascript Projects\IARA-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
> at SMTPConnection._actionMAIL (c:\Javascript Projects\IARA-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1566:34)
> at SMTPConnection. (c:\Javascript Projects\IARA-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1041:18)
> at SMTPConnection._processResponse (c:\Javascript Projects\IARA-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
> at SMTPConnection._onData (c:\Javascript Projects\IARA-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
> at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (c:\Javascript Projects\IARA-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
> at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
> code: 'EENVELOPE',
> response: '530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n' +
> '530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError dy43-20020a056870c7ab00b00101cdb417f1sm5627633oab.22 - gsmtp',
> responseCode: 530,
> command: 'MAIL FROM'
> }

Comment: You mentioned **I copy all necessary values to node.js CLIENT_ID , CLIENT_SECRET, refresh_tokens**. That method is for testing and you will need to periodically recreate the tokens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Resolve Error Sending Email Using nodemailer googleapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560138/how-to-resolve-error-sending-email-using-nodemailer-googleapi)

Comment: @JohnHanley I really copied everything to nodejs I just remove from stackoverflow for secure purposes. I think it's not related with lack of information on nodejs

Comment: I would suspect that your issue is in googleApiUtil.  Its not getting you an access token.  can we see some code for that.

Comment: @DaImTo I console.log the values got on **"oAuth2Client.refreshAccessToken()"** and it has returned both refresh and access tokens

Comment: I think you should try hooking in to the google api node.js client library to build your access token.   I use the google .net client library to get my access token using C# and smtpclient

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved the issue, the best solution I got, whenever I call the `oAuth2Client.refreshAccessToken()` function I save all returned credentials such as  **refresh_token**, **access_token** on a config file (.json), so when I call to send e-mail I got those credentials updated from config file. It's was quite easy actually, sorry for open a silly question here on Stackoverflow.